# Why do we sometimes need to clear the 'error' or 'data' of a mutation request in RQ?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, mutation

I was browsing `Tanstack Query v4`, about Mutations in RQ.

However, I found an option `mutation.reset()`.

Description says that users who use RQ sometimes need to clear the `error` and `data` of a mutation request which I'm having trouble understanding the concept of resetting mutations.

I came up with two possible answers why we need to resetting the outcomes of mutations.

1. `error` and `data` is a client-side resources which can lead to bad performance if size of either of them becomes larger.
2. it is safe to clear the `error` and `data` as further mutations will be made.

still, I don't understand the proper concept of `Resetting Mutation State`, and I want to understand why do we have to reset mutations.

What I'm trying to understand from this question :

1. Understanding the concept of resetting mutations.
2. Advantages of resetting mutations.

link : https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/mutations